# How to represent the member of generated sigma algebra in terms of unions and complements?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra over a set $\Omega$. For any $E\in\sigma(\mathscr{A})$, prove $E$ can be represented as countable union and complements which belong to $\mathscr{A}$. Can someone give a hint?

---

The difficulty I have with this problem is that the definition of $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ is not constructive:
$$\sigma(\mathscr{A})=\cap\{\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{F},\mathscr{‌​F}\text{ is a sigma algebra over }\Omega\}$$

Comment: Consider the definition of $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$

Comment: @Adam Hughes. I have been working on the definition of $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ for several hours. The definition is $\sigma(\mathscr{A})=\cap\{\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{F},\mathscr{F}\text{ is a sigma algebra over }\Omega\}$

Comment: Oof, that version is terrible, no wonder you're having issues. Try and consider the alternate definition which is more constructive.

Comment: @Adam Hughes.Our textbook only provides this definition. Can you provide alternative definition and the proof that both of definition are equivalent?

Comment: @AdamHughes I think that the point of this exercise is exactly to prove the "constructive" definition you are referring to.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro yes, I realized that after he gave the definition he's working with, but thanks for double checking everyone was on the same page. :-)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro.@ Adam Hughes This problem is one part of one of my problem. I need to prove this, then I can go further of the whole problem.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro.@AdamHughes. Can you provide any hint?

Comment: Could you be more precise about "countable union and complements"? Do you mean that every element of $\sigma(\scr A)$ is of the form $\bigcup_nA_n$ or $\Omega\setminus\bigcup_nA_n$ for $A_n\in\scr A$? (Can probably answer this...)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I mean $\sigma(\mathscr{A})=\{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}, A_{i}\in\mathscr{A}\}\cup\{\Omega-\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}, A_{i}\in\mathscr{A}\}$. At the beginning, I thought it only needs $\{\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}, A_{i}\in\mathscr{A}\}$, but later I realized it needs something which is not in $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: @MikeBrown That's definitely false because the set you wrote down is equal to $\scr A$, since $\scr A$ is an algebra. You need to work countable unions $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ in somewhere.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro. Can you tell me how to start it? Like First prove...., then prove.....

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sigma(\scr A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\scr A$, the usual way to prove that every $E\in\sigma(\scr A)$ has a property is to show that the set of all sets with the property is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\scr A$. So let $${\scr P}=\{\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}A_{nk}:A_{nk}\in A\}.$$

Obviously $\scr A\subseteq P$; we need to show that $\scr P$ is closed under complement and countable union. A countable union of sets in $\scr P$ is $\bigcup_{i,n\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}A_{ink}$, which is in $\scr P$ because $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable. Showing that $\scr P$ is closed under complement is more interesting - can you prove it? (It may actually be false; if so then you will need to extend the characterization of $\scr P$ to sets of the form $\bigcup_{n_1\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k_1\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{n_2\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k_2\in\Bbb N}\dots A_{n_1n_2\dots k_1k_2\dots}$ for either countably many or $\omega_1$ many alternations of intersection and union of elements of $\scr A$. See also the proof that [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) are explicitly generated by iterating countable union and complement on the open sets $\omega_1$ times.)

Comment: How do you define $A_{ink}$?

Comment: It is a given: We have a countable union of sets $P_i,i\in\Bbb N$, and for each one, by definition of $\scr P$ they have a decomposition $P_i=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}A_{ink}$.